# Difference between the increase in optical path due to refraction and that due to reflection

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, geometric-optics, lenses

If we place two glass plates of refractive index $\mu$ and each having thickness $t ,$ on the way of a light ray the increase in the optical path becomes
$$
     \left(S_2 P - S_1 P \right)
 = 2 \left(\mu - 1\right) t
$$
due to refraction through them, and the path difference (or extra path traversed by light) due to reflection at the second surface of one glass plate is $2 \mu t \cos{\left(\alpha\right)} .$

Without seeing the expression if we look at the phenomenon directly, aren't they basically same, as both are going through a glass media of the same length?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to draw a diagram to explain what you mean

Comment: The experiment you are describing is very unclear. How many sources are there? How many beams? Which ones are you considering (reflected, transmitted, which surface...)? Please provide some additional information.

Comment: I have said that in first line "a light ray",and also the reflection is at second surface of the plate..